# Recyclerview empty view appears

Tags: android, arraylist, fragment, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am creating a android app for food store.I am using **Recyclerview** in android to show the list of Items.

Here I have two categories, 1) veg and 2) non-veg and I has used segmented button here to jump from Veg to Non-veg Items.

To jump from veg to non-veg and vice-versa, I am simply calling a method of fragment, and from that I am doing following.

```
categoriesItemsAdapter = new CategoriesItemsAdapter(mContext,pojoCategoryItems);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesItemsAdapter);
```

Here **pojoCategoryItems** is a new list after changing from veg to non-veg and vice-versa.

But, **Recyclerview** adds blank view above my new list of Items.

[image: before]

[image: after click on non-veg, you can see blank over new image]

How can I tackle it?

Thank in advance techies.

Comment: Have you used `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesItemsAdapter);` multiple times ? (My be from different fragment). If so then I suggest clearing the List once and notify and again set the adapter and notify.

Comment: noup.....I am not calling multiple times and when a click happens I am crating new adapter and setting to recyclerview view again with new items

Comment: categoriesItemsAdapter = new CategoriesItemsAdapter(mContext,pojoCategoryItems);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesItemsAdapter);

Comment: If so then I suggest to try clearing the previous List once, notify and again set the adapter with new list items and notify.